# Unable to find datatype after declaring xml schema namespace

Tags: xml, schema

I am unable to understand certain behavior of declaring XML schema .

Question 
This xml schema works fine :

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://www.example.org" xmlns:ab="http://test.com"
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="simple1" type="complexType1"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="complexType1">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="element1" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>*
```

But if I change targetnamespace  anything apart from http://www.example.org , the schema does not find complexType1. Why this happens.
This does not work.

```
*<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="http://www.example.org" xmlns:ab="http://test.com"
            targetNamespace="http://www.example.org99999"
            elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:element name="simple1" type="complexType1"/>

  <xsd:complexType name="complexType1">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="element1" type="xsd:string"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>*
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare a component such as a `complexType`, it goes in the `targetNamespace` of the schema. When you reference a component with an unprefixed name, as in your `type="complexType1"` attribute, this is taken as a reference to the default namespace (declared in the xmlns attribute). In your first example the `targetNamespace` and the default namespace are the same, so it works; in the second example they are different, so it doesn't.

How to fix it? That depends on what you are trying to achieve, which you haven't told us.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for answering he question. I still do not understand the part "When you declare a component such as a complexType, it goes in the targetNamespace of the schema". I have declared xsd:complexType. I have used xsd prefix. Then why will xsd:complexType goes to the target namespace?

Comment: You misunderstood my answer. When you write in the schema `<xsd:complexType name="foo"/>`, the effect is to declare a type whose local name is "foo" and whose namespace is the targetNamespace of the containing schema document.